# Git confusion, conflicts with yourself

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I have a `master` branch that rejects pushes from anyone. We only work in `branches`, so if a user wants to make something in the codebase, it has to:

- git checkout -b FEATURE
- git add .
- git commit -m "Commits"
- git push origin FEATURE

Next step is to review code in `bitbucket`, if the review fails, the programmer continues his line of work:

- git checkout FEATURE
- git add .
- git commit -m "Commits"
- git push origin FEATURE ** Now this step fails **

The last push fails saying that you need to pull code because whatever. So the programmer execute a `git pull origin FEATURE` and then, CONFLICTS EVERYWHERE. **Nobody but the programmer pushed code to the FEATURE branch, so there's nothing new there**. Why this happens?

Another problem, the `master` branch is cloned in a `QA` machine, so we have a `Jenkins` integration that based on some conditions, log in with ssh in this machine and:

- cd /path/to/cloned/master
- git pull origin master

The thing is, why after doing this i am greeted with a message:

# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 46 commits.

The `master` branch is pull only, if i am doing a `git pull` it means the code in the machine is the same as the `origin/master` right? Also this is prone to conflicts, as it has happen before. A few months before after a `git pull origin master` on the `QA` machine, the `master` branch conflicted with itself...

I could use some enlightment here to try understanding this evil black magic that is `git` flows and `branches` and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> The last push fails saying that you need to pull code because whatever. So the programmer execute a  git pull origin FEATURE and then, CONFLICTS EVERYWHERE. Why this happens?

You need to push it to the tip of the branch. In order to do that, you need to do a "git pull --rebase origin master" before you push your code. That would fetch the master branch and rebase your work so that your commits will be placed just after the last commit of the master branch.

I am assuming that the pull must be done against the master branch because the FEATURE branch is only used by a single programmer, that FEATURE only exists in the programmer's local copy, and you don't want a persistent FEATURE branch, but a push-review-merge branch.

The whole sequence would be:

`git checkout FEATURE
git add .
git commit -m "Commits"
git pull --rebase origin master
git push origin FEATURE`

Answer (score 1):

**1.For the first question: last push fail.** The commit history on feature branch must be different (maybe local feature branch was not based on latest version or update and feature branch on bitbucket by accident) before the programmer pushed second time. To figure it out, you need to compare the commits from local feature branch and remote feature branch:

```
git fetch origin feature
git log feature..origin/feature   #If it has output, that means the remote feature branch was update
git log origin/feature..feature   #check if it only shows the commit(s) that’s the programmer committed second time
```

**2.For the second question: local master branch is ahead of origin/master branch after git pull.** The function of git pull is only to make sure commits on remote master branch are also exist locally. Illustrate as below graphs:

```
A---B---C                      origin/master
A---B---C---D1---D2---…---D46  master
```

When you execute `git pull origin master`, it only make sure the commit A,B and C is on local master branch.

If there has changes on remote master branch (commit E):

```
A---B---C---E                  origin/master
A---B---C---D1---D2---…---D46  master
```

When you execute `git pull origin master`, there will have merge conflict if both of them modified same files.

```
          E                    origin/master
         /
A---B---C---D1---D2---…---D46  master


          ___________E__________        origin/master
         /                      \
A---B---C---D1---D2---…---D46--- M      master
```

So be used to use g`it status`, `git log branch...origin/branch` and `git log origin/branch..branch`, these commands will keep you clearly about local/remote versions.

Answer (score 0):

> The last push fails saying that you need to pull code because
>   whatever. So the programmer execute a git pull origin FEATURE and
>   then, CONFLICTS EVERYWHERE. Why this happens?

It happens because someone committed the code to `FEATURE` either directly or through pull request in time between you created the pull request for review and fixed the review comments and tried to push again.

> Another problem, the master branch is cloned in a QA machine, so we
>   have a Jenkins integration that based on some conditions, log in with
>   ssh in this machine and:
>
> cd /path/to/cloned/master git pull origin master The thing is, why
>   after doing this i am greeted with a message:
>
> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 46 commits.

This message appear only if someone made commits to master(in QA machine) or someone merged `local/remote` branch and updated master code not yet pushed to remote.

Comment: I updated the question that now reads: `Nobody but the programmer pushed code to the FEATURE branch, so there's nothing new there`